# Is it offensive answers

Tags: discussion

I'm a kind of newbie at the site, so would like to hear your opinion about answers like https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30604/12293
To me it seems a bit offensive,  from the other side the question creator *require* some very specific feature from the free product.

Comment: What's offensive about that comment?

Comment: @Marius, have edited the answer as the link was wrong.  I'm refereeing the answer #2.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that answer is offensive. It comes down a bit hard, but still the man has a point.
But this is my opinion.

And now the good part. If you have a different opinion I see 2 possible actions here.

1. You don't like the answer - down vote it.
2. You thing the answer is offensive and or abusive just flag it. A moderator will review your flag and may agree with you or not.

Comment: I was direct with my answer so that it was clear the task he was trying to do is not a good idea. I mean, `eval()`? Really?